# How to access "Elements" in the page having "same attributes and tag names" using "Protractor" for "Angular 4 application"

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

The "Angular application" web page which i have to write "Protractor automation script" have below code.
for "Name" text box field "validation" message display

```
<div class="ui-message ui-messages-error ui-corner-all">
                    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                        Name is required
                     </div>
```

for "Certificate type" drop down field "validation message" display

```
<div class="ui-message ui-messages-error ui-corner-all">
                    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                        CertificationsType is required
                     </div>
```

I would like "write test script" for "validation message content verification" for both fields. But what my question "Both field validation messages" uses same "class name and same attributes" in this if i am using "class name or tag name" then i can able to access only "Name" field validation message ,i couldn't able to access "Type drop down field" validation message.

So can any one help me how to access "Type" field validation message using "Protractor test script".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element.all(by.css('.ui-message'))` will return you an array of each div which have `ui-message` as class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is working. I am able to access "Type" field validation message using "array index" ( list[1] )